# Using max function causes bytes used to increase

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to tune a query that is causing excessive temp space issues. I notice that for a particular section of the query:

```
Select group_id,  
item,
max(greatest(height,width,length)) length, 
max(greatest(least(height,length),least(height,width),least(width,length))) width, 
Max(least(length,width,height) height  
From items  
where group_id = 1  
group by group_id, item
```

Rows,Bytes columns go from 961M,27G to 680M,43G.

```
PX SEND HASH    :TQ20044    680M    43G HASH
VIEW        680M    43G 
HASH GROUP BY       680M    19G
PX RECEIVE      961M    27G
PX SEND HASH    :TQ20042    961M    27G HASH
PX BLOCK ITERATOR       961M    27G 
TABLE ACCESS FULL   item_table  961M    27G
```

Why would selecting max values cause the Bytes column to nearly double in size. Is there some way I can change this to not use so much?

----Update----
After looking at the tables a bit more, `item_table`'s primary key is `<group_id, item>` and also has a partition column on `group_id`. Removing the unnecessary group by and aggregation functions lowered the bytes read but I still do not understand why the Bytes column went up instead of down after the initial filter of `group_id = 1`.

Comment: Just a side note: in this particular query grouping and filtering on `group_id` simultaneously makes no sense.

Comment: Group_id is a partition column and <group_id,item> forms the primary key. I agree it doesn't make sense, but I don't know why the original developer wrote it this way. I did remove the group by and the aggregation functions  and it did lower the bytes and row count. However, I have no idea why the Bytes column was so high. Googling around for explain plans explains the cost and rows columns but not the bytes. So I was hoping someone could give an explanation of what was happening.